# Fontawesome stack alignment problems

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, font-awesome

I have used the used the code example on Fontawesome's website to create two stacked social media buttons and wrapped it in a div to float them to the right of the page.

```
<div class="social-icons">
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i> 
<i class="fa fa-instagram fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span> 
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg"> 
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i> 
<i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i> 
</span>
</div>
```

The icon and the circle that it should align with appear to be aligned to the top and not the middle despite taking the styling from http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css.

Comment: Please add your CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

did you use this in between your `head` tag?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
```

then i think you values are incorrect

```
<i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i>
<i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
......
```

> check them all from [fontawesome website](https://fontawesome.com/icons)
>   then use the fontawesome cdn:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
```